# Relase api key for google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore

I am about to launch my app which contains google maps. Earlier I get SHA1 from Windows>Preferance>Android>Build>SHA1 fingerprint . Then I went to google developer console and made api key by SHA1; package name. I have been doing this for testing.

Now I need to release my app to play store. I have made a new keystore  and there by at the end apk is formed.

Now some articles are saying I need a diffrent sha1 for releasing google map. I read a tutorial which made sha 1 from keystore in command prompt and we get another SHA1 finger print. So now I am trying to make api key with this sha1 and putting in manifest. Am I missing something? Am I on right track?

Comment: You are on right way. So don't worry. Keep going .

Comment: but i have a doubt. when i get a new sha 1 fingerprint and put that in app. Then which apk i need to put on playstore? since the apk is already formes at the time of making keystore. Please i am a newby so clear my doubt

Comment: @JackieChan create the apk again with the new keys

Comment: anirudh you mean to say once i put the new key in manifest. i should run the project and that is my final apk that is in bin folder? or you want to say something else

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track, but as you said you are a newbie let me help you with details:

- You already had an API key for Google Maps which was made using the debug SHA1 key.
- Once you have a `keystore` the you gonna use to sign your `release` APKs (for app's lifetime), extract the SHA1 from this `keystore` using the same command prompt method.
- SHA1 is dependent on the "keystore" files, so it will also remain same for app's lifetime.
- Now, you just need to update the old SHA1 for your API key to this one. API key will remain same and you can directly use it.